# converting javascript code to unreadable

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

how can i convert

```
http
```

to

```
h$#t!t@@^#p
```

i have seen this code which was automatically injected into my site.......

is there and md5 like php function or their is any other way

Comment: Please clarify. What are you asking?

Comment: Looking at some of your earlier questions, is your main concern is how could someone maliciously distort your javascript into unreadable code?

Comment: I'd be rather more concerned about fixing the exploit that let the Russians compromise your site!

Comment: Yeah, with such wicked language you risk running afoul of the Communication Decency Act (CDA) too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called [*obfuscation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation). You can find a list of tools in many SO questions. For example:

- [How can I obfuscate JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)
- [What is the best javascript obfuscator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522064/what-is-the-best-javascript-obfuscator)
- [Free JavaScript obfuscators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272342/free-javascript-obfuscators)

Answer (score 1):

What you search for is **Obfuscation**.

This one works with PHP and pretty good:
http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/1863.html

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want.

```
var txt = "http";
console.log(btoa(txt));  //gives you "aHR0cA=="
```